# Check if 2 nodes are adjacent in binary tree using linkedlish C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, boolean, binary-search-tree

Sorry for the bad English.
I'm creating a binary tree project by using a linked list in C++. And Im trying to make a boolean method to check if 2 nodes are adjacent or not?
And I'm trying to use the recursion method as I'm using the linked list to do this, but it seems I did it wrong.

Here is how I declare the Node

```
    Struct Node{
        string name;
        int data;
        Node *right, *left;
    }
```

And here is how I declare the checking function:

```
bool checkadjacent(node* Node, string& u, string& v) {
    if(!Node){
        return false;
    }
    if (Node && Node->right) {
        string current = Node->name;
        string right = Node->right->name;
        if (current == u && right == v)
            return true;
        else if (current == v && right == u)
            return true;
    }
    if (Node && Node->left) {
        string current = Node->name;
        string left = Node->left->name;
        if (current == u && left == v)
            return true;
        else if (current == v && left == u)
            return true;
    }
    if (Node->left){
        if(checkadjacent(Node->left, u, v)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (Node->right){
        if(checkadjacent(Node->right, u, v)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by adjacent in binary tree? parent-child relation? If that is the case, just check if one is the child of other. And how can you represent a binary tree using only one linked list?

Answer (score 1):

Note: "it seems I did it wrong" is not an explanation of how your code fials. Always describe what your code is SUPPOSED to do and what it is ACTUALLY doing.

Having said that, I'm assuming your code does not compile. I put together a (possibly non-comprehensive) list of errors and other problems with your code, aswell as a corrected version of your code. However, I would advise you to watch some tutorials about C++ (or C if you want, since your code is basically C code), because your code shows some serious misunderstandings and neglection. Apart from that, your basic idea seems correct except for the last bullet point in the following list.

List of problems:

- It's `struct` not `Struct` (capitalization matters in C++). (This is necessary for correctness/syntax)
- In the declaration of `Node` you capitalize the name of the Node. Later, you call it `node` and instead capitalize the name of the object which instantiates `Node` (to be consistent, I called the struct `Node` and it's instantiation `node`). (This is necessary for correctness/syntax)
- First you check whether Node is actually pointing to a struct: `if(!Node)`. This is good, but there is no need to check the same thing again later: `if (Node && Node->right)` and `if (Node && Node->left)` just leave out the first part in both conditions: `if (node->right)` and `if (node->left)`. (This is for style)
- Then you can also leave out the 3rd and 4th if statements and put their block into the 1st and 2nd if blocks respectively. (This is for style)
- Do not declare the variables `current`, `right` and `left` inside the if blocks, instead declare them at the beginning of the function. (This is for style)
- For the algorithm to work you have to return false if none of the if none of the if statements are executed (this is a guess; I did not test this and you WILL have to try that yourself). (This is necessary for correctness/semantics)

Here's the full code (note that I did **NOT** test this code, as your problem was clearly faulty syntax and not algorithm design.

```
bool checkadjacent(Node* node, string& u, string& v) {
    string current, left, right;

    if (!node) {
        return false;
    }
    if (node->right) {
        current = node->name;
        right = node->right->name;
        if (current == u && right == v)
            return true;
        else if (current == v && right == u)
            return true;

        // recursion
        if (checkadjacent(node->right, u, v)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (node->left) {
        current = node->name;
        left = node->left->name;
        if (current == u && left == v)
            return true;
        else if (current == v && left == u)
            return true;

        // recursion
        if (checkadjacent(node->left, u, v)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also note:

- I did not change the definition of `Node`.
- Apart from `string` your code is just C code. In C++ you have the possibility to create a class for the binary tree which would be a lot more readable.
- There are no linked lists in any parts of the code above (neither in the code you posted). The fact that the node have left and right child nodes, does not make it a linked list (in particular it's not a list because it is not 1-dimensional).
- Again, I did **NOT** test this code; you can do that yourself.